# Problemas con Handlebars

Tags: javascript, nodejs, handlebars.js, handlebars

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con NodeJS y MongoDB. Una de las funcionalidades de dicha aplicación es la subida de imágenes, la cual funciona correctamente; pero a la hora de mostrar las imágenes subidas la aplicación tarda una eternidad en cargarse. Tratando de encontrar la causa, he mirado en la consola y he visto este mensaje de error: "Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "filename" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details". Sin embargo en el esquema de la base de datos sí que hay una propiedad llamada "filename", tal y como se puede comprobar en esta imagen:[image: Esquema de mi base de datos MongoDB]
La parte del código de la aplicación donde hago uso de esa propiedad es ésta: [image: Código del archivo 'index.hbs']
¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

**PD: ** Como tenía la aplicación abierta para comprobar si se veían las imágenes, la he refrescado, y ahora lo que no reconoce Handlebars es la constante virtual 'uniqueId', que también existe en el esquema de la base de datos. El mensaje de error que me muestra ahora es el siguiente: "Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "uniqueId" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details". Sin embargo sí reconoce que hay imágenes en la base de datos, tal y como se puede comprobar en la siguiente captura de pantalla: [image: Parte de mi aplicación donde se muestran las imágenes guardadas en la base de datos ordenadas por fecha de creación de mayor a menor.]

Comment: Por favor, sube tu código como texto, no como imagen. Es más fácil para intentar reproducir tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, me lo apunto para la siguiente vez que tenga algún problema con algún que otro programa que esté creando en algún otro momento :).

Comment: @SCC38 edita tu pregunta, el texto se mantiene con el tiempo, una imagen puede perderse si el server le da de baja y/o alguna otra cosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install handlebars@4.5.3` para instalar otra versión de handlebars e importalo a config.js

```
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
```

en el config es la parte de exphbs agregas un nuevo objeto llamado handlebars y lo igual a importado

queda asi :

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    helpers: require('./helpers'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    handlebars: handlebars
}));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, en cuanto pueda lo probaré y ya diré cómo me fue.

Comment: Ante todo perdonadme por tardar tanto en contestar, pero he estado muy ocupado con otros proyectos y no he podido hacerlo hasta ahora. El problema ya quedó resuelto.

Answer (score 3):

Hace poco me encontre con este problema y no me gusto la solucion de instalar una vieja dependencia asi que lo solucione utilizando la funcion .lean() de mongose detras de mi consulta .find() para que me retornara un objeto json no un documento mongoose..

```
dbName.find({}).lean()
```

y asi utilizar las llaves del objeto tal cual en nuestra plantilla. Una ventaja extra de esta solucion es que lean() es bastante mas rapido en comparacion que el find() solo.. Para el problema de arriba:

```
const images = await Image.find().sort({timestamp: -1}).lean()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has salvado mi dia. Llevo todo el dia solucionandolo