# Problema con #each Handlebars

Tags: nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Tengo este codigo

```html
<section>
    {{#each popularImages}}
        <div class="image-group">
            {{!-- {{this}} --}} ---------------------> Si funciona
            {{#each this}}
                <div class="image-row">
                    {{!-- {{this.filename}} --}} ----> No Funciona
                    {{ filename }} ------------------> Tampoco funciona
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

y los datos que se pasan son estos

```
[
  [
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
  ],
  [...]
]
```

Y cuando accedo no me muestra ningún dato, quisiera hacer un foreach que recorre el array de arrays y dentro otro foreach que recorre los subarrays y mostrar algun dato del objeto

Me muestra este texto en la consola

```
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "filename" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.

You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:

See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
```

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, encontre la solucion [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352085/problemas-con-handlebars)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas con Handlebars](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352085/problemas-con-handlebars)

Comment: En ese caso, la pregunta va para cerrarse por duplicada